# Access two listboxes that have many to many relationship

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access2017 database. On a form I have "PLCS Group" mulit-select listbox and "IPS Elements" the second multi-select listbox.

```
-----FIRST LIST-----
ID
GRAPES
APPLES
CHERRIES
LETTUCE
--------------------

-----SECOND LIST----
FK
COLD
DARK
LEAVE IN SUN
DIED
---------------------

So if someone selected GRAPES and APPLES from first list. And selected COLD,DIED from second list

This is what the second table should have it it.
GRAPES,COLD
GRAPES,DIED
APPLES,COLD
APPLES,DIED
```

I tried nesting the second listbox's records but that didn't update the tables.
I changed my code to what was suggested, But now I'm getting error 3020 "Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit"

I have AddNew statements in it I'm not sure what's making it not recognize them. If I comment out the second loop the first listboxes items are saved.
HERE'S MY UPDATED CODE:

```
Dim db            As DAO.Database
Dim rs            As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2            As DAO.Recordset
Dim ctl           As Control
Dim ctl2           As Control
Dim varItem       As Variant
Dim varItem2        As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("ProposalTracker3", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("IPSElementsDetails", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)


Set ctl  = Me.PLCSGroupListBox
Set ctl2 = Me.IPSList

For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
            rs!GACP = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
        rs.Update
    For Each varItem2 In ctl2.ItemsSelected
        rs2.AddNew
            rs2!ProposalID = Me.txtID
            rs2!Element = ctl2.ItemData(varItem2)
        rs.Update
    Next varItem2
rs2.Close
Next varItem
rs.Close
db.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want all possible combinations of the selected items of the two list boxes. You combine the entries with two nested loops

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("DestinationTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

Set lb1 = Me.PLCSGroupListBox
Set lb2 = Me.IPSList
For Each item1 In lb1.ItemsSelected
    For Each item2 In lb2.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
        rs!Somefield = lb1.ItemData(item1) & ',' & lb2.ItemData(item2)
        rs!ProposalID = Me.ID
        rs.Update
    Next item2
Next item1
rs.Close
db.Close
```

Or maybe you want to add the values from the two list boxes to two separate fields

```
rs.AddNew
rs!Somefield = lb1.ItemData(item1)
rs!Anotherfield = lb2.ItemData(item2)
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Oliver Jacot-Descombes So would I put the first list box's data to add after the inner loop? The list boxes go into two different tables.

Comment: My code shows only what should go to the second table. You can add stuff coming from `lb1` to the other table before or after the inner loop. The nested loops create the combinations `GRAPES,COLD
GRAPES,DIED
APPLES,COLD
APPLES,DIED`, the out loop creates `GRAPES   APPLES`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm trying it out right now.

Comment: @Oliver Jacot-Descombes I tried updating the code as you suggested. It wouldn't work with "lbl.itemselected" so I changed it to "ctl". Now it's saying it doesn't find the AddNew I have in the loop. What do you suggest?

Comment: My code is just pseudo-code. The idea is that you use `lb1` and `lb2` instead of `ctl`, because `lb` (list box) says more than just `ctl` and you need two of them. But of course you must declare them: `Dim lb1 As ListBox, lb2 As ListBox` and also `Dim item1 As Variant, item2 As Variant` or keep `varItem1` and `varItem2`.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you close `rs2` inside the loop. This does not work, as it will be closed at the 2nd iteration. Close everything after the loops!

Comment: thank you Oliver. Declaring the lbl as a listbox did the trick.